# Why grant_type is not in OpenIddictRequest parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, openiddict

I have an endPoint service with the following prototype:
`async Task<IActionResult> Exchange(OpenIddictRequest openIdRequest)`
I send a postMan request like below:
[image]

As you can see, I'm sending 4 parameters, and particulary I provide parameter **grant_type** with value **password**.
But when I check the parameters in the back-end I just get 3 parameters like below:

[image]

When I check with `openIdRequest.IsPasswordGrantType()` method it returns `false`.

If I add a new parameter with name **grantType** and value **password** I get 4 paramters and the method `openIdRequest.IsPasswordGrantType()` returns true. You can see it in the following images:

[image]

And in the backend:

[image]

If I replace the parameter **grant_type** with parameter **grantType** I get this error:

> openiddict the mandatory 'grant_type' parameter is missing

can anyone guide me please?
(I'm using **OpenIddict: version 3.1.1** and **.net 6**)

Comment: Hi @Developer Can you please help me on the same type issue that I am getting for .Net core API and OpenIdDict. I have posted my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73383197/getopeniddictserverrequest-always-returning-null-value-for-openiddict-in-net

Comment: @Basanta Matia What do you send in your request header in UI?

Comment: Now, I am able to pass data from Postman to API. However, I am not getting any Token from Server. I have posted a question here, can you please have a look on this.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73383197/openiddict-not-returning-token-from-net-core-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
I changed the **Exchange** Method prototype
from :

```
Task<IActionResult> Exchange(OpenIddictRequest openIdRequest)
```

to:

```
Task<IActionResult> Exchange()
```

and got the **openIdRequest** from **HttpContext** like below:

```
var openIdRequest = HttpContext.GetOpenIddictServerRequest();
```

Now I can see all of those parameters in my **openIdRequest**.