# OpenIdDict not returning Token from .Net Core API

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, openid-connect, openid

I have a .Net Core API project, where I'm using OpenIDDict to authenticate. I refered there [official repository](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples/blob/dev/samples/Imynusoph/Imynusoph.Server/Controllers/AuthorizationController.cs) however it is not returning Token to end user (currently i'm testing with postman)

Here is my Program.cs file

```
  //OPENID
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{ options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ApplicationDb"));
    options.UseOpenIddict();
});

// Register the Identity services.
//builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
//    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
//    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType = Claims.Name;
    options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = Claims.Subject;
    options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType = Claims.Role;
    options.ClaimsIdentity.EmailClaimType = Claims.Email;
});

builder.Services.AddQuartz(options =>
{
    options.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory();
    options.UseSimpleTypeLoader();
    options.UseInMemoryStore();
});

builder.Services.AddOpenIddict()

    // Register the OpenIddict core components.
    .AddCore(options =>
    {
            // Configure OpenIddict to use the Entity Framework Core stores and models.
            // Note: call ReplaceDefaultEntities() to replace the default OpenIddict entities.
        options.UseEntityFrameworkCore()
               .UseDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();

            // Enable Quartz.NET integration.
        options.UseQuartz();
    })

    // Register the OpenIddict server components.
    .AddServer(options =>
    {
            // Enable the token endpoint.
        options.SetTokenEndpointUris("/connect/token");
        options.AllowPasswordFlow();
        options.AcceptAnonymousClients();
        options.AddDevelopmentEncryptionCertificate()
               .AddDevelopmentSigningCertificate();
        options.UseAspNetCore()
               .EnableTokenEndpointPassthrough();
    })

    // Register the OpenIddict validation components.
    .AddValidation(options =>
    {
        options.UseLocalServer();
        options.UseAspNetCore();
    });...
```

My AuthorizationController.cs file

```
 [HttpPost("~/connect/token"), Produces("application/json")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Exchange()
{
    var request = HttpContext.GetOpenIddictServerRequest();
    var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal();
    if (request.IsPasswordGrantType())
    {
        try
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(request.Username);
            if (user == null)
            {
                //Return Error message
            }

            var result = await _signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, request.Password, lockoutOnFailure: true);
            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                 //Return Error message
            }
            var principal = await _signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(user);
            principal.SetScopes(new[]
            {
            Scopes.OpenId,
            Scopes.Email,
            Scopes.Profile,
            Scopes.Roles
        }.Intersect(request.GetScopes()));

            foreach (var claim in principal.Claims)
            {
                claim.SetDestinations(GetDestinations(claim, principal));
            }
            return SignIn(principal, OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
 ...
```

It should return a token similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42561144/2376652) however I am getting 500 status in postman.
The error is **The entity type 'OpenIddictEntityFrameworkCoreToken' was not found. Ensure that the entity type has been added to the model.**

Not sure, I need to create tables for this ? Or I missed something ? I can see in [official OpenIdDict site](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples/tree/dev/samples/Hollastin/Hollastin.Server), they haven't mentioned anything like that.

I'm using .Net 6, VS 2022.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding ?

```cs
services.AddIdentity<User, Role>()
    .AddSignInManager()
    .AddUserStore<UserStore>()
    .AddRoleStore<RoleStore>()
    .AddUserManager<UserManager<User>>();
```

[Check this blog](https://nwb.one/blog/openid-connect-dotnet-5)